# How to make Flutter scrollable_positioned_list package like Gridview Style

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using below package in. my project to jump spesific index. It is working fine when the view is list but i wanted to implement gridview style but no chance.

https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Basicly it is using SliverList, i changed to it SliverGrid but when I go to any index below and scroll up again - everything breaks.

So how can i make the list gridView.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put `CustomScrollView` in your gridview class and then wrap it  inside SliverToBoxAdapter() in somewhere class that you want to call the gradview widget, just like this:

```
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: _gridViewClass(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Himm, actually i forked that package changed SliverList to SliverGrid, i am having problem with calculation.